Selforthogonal modules and finitistic dimension
Algebras $A$ are always finite dimensional over a field here.
A module $M$ is called selforthogonal if $\operatorname{Ext}_A^i(M,M)=0$ for all $i>0$.
Define the orthogonal finitistic dimension $\operatorname{ofindim} A$ of an algebra $A$ as $\sup\{ \operatorname{pdim} M \mid M \ \text{is selforthogonal and} \ \operatorname{pdim} M < \infty \}$.
Here are some experimental observations for Nakayama algebras with the computer:
-$\operatorname{findim} A=\operatorname{ofindim}A$
-$A$ is Iwanaga-Gorenstein if and only if every orthogonal module has finite projective dimension.

Question 1: Do those two statements hold in general for finite dimensional algebras?


Question 2: Call an algebra $A$ selforthogonal if every indecomposable module is selforthgonal. I can show that (over an algebraically closed field) $A$ is representation finite and of finite global dimension. Do we even have that $A$ has finite global dimension bounded by the number of simple $A$-modules minus one ? This is true for acyclic algebras.


I was $(100-\varepsilon)%$ sure that you intended a supremum in the definition of $\operatorname{ofindim}A$, so I edited to add it. Apologies if I was wrong.

@JeremyRickard Yes, thank you!
